# Performance in update partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I am running a postgres query

```
Update table_1 aa
set Net_Price = case when bb.source = 'A' then coalesce(bb.price,0)
                        else aa.net_price end,
    Core_price = case when bb.source = 'B' then coalesce(bb.price,0)
                        else aa.Core_price end 
from table_2 bb
where aa.country_code = bb.country_code
and aa.dealer_id = bb.dealer_ID
```

More Information:

- Table 1 has 19.4 million records
- Table 2 has 8.2 million records
- The column    "Source" in table 2 can have only 2 values A (8 million rows) and B (200,000 rows)
- Country codes can    have 10 possible values like C1, C2, C3... C10

This query was taking 21 minutes to run average. To bring it to more desirable time I made some changes in the tables.

As the country codes can have 10 possible values I list partitioned both the tables on country code.

I also created BTREE indexes on both the tables(like table_1_idx_1 on country_code, table_1_idx_2 on dealer_id, table_2_idx_1 on country_code, table_2_idx_2 on dealer_id)

I was thinking maybe this will help but now the query is now taking 25 minutes to run average. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because the cost have largely decreased after making these changes. I am out of ideas what can I do better to make this run in significantly lesser time.

EDIT 1: The tables BTW has already existing indexes on combinations of country_code + dealer_id

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? The query will be sent executed, but returns the complete queryplan and other details. Please use plain text

Comment: The ddl for both tables and all indexes would be welcome as well

Comment: @FrankHeikens These are names I have created as I cannot access sign in via facebook on my work laptop. For the same reason I wont be able to give you the actual explain plan also. Can I pastebin it and share?

Comment: Restricting the set of matching rows to only those that will actually change might improve performance.

Comment: As others have said, to help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.